# Переменная sensors не может быть типом int

Tags: arduino

Ругается иде на то что переменная sensors не может быть типом int. при переводе в тип инт методом `int tmp; tmp = (int)sensors;` выдает такую ошибку `invalid cast from type "DallasTemperature" to type int`

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
// Провод данных подключен к контакту 2 на Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
#define Rele 5
// Настройка oneWire для связи с любыми устройствами OneWire
// (не только Maxim/Dallas температурные IC)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);



int tmp;
int PotenciometrPin = A0;
int val;
void setup(void)
{
pinMode(Rele, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(Rele, HIGH);
lcd.init();
lcd.backlight();// Включаем подсветку дисплея


}

void loop(void)
{

lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Отправляем команды для получения температуры
val = analogRead(PotenciometrPin);
lcd.print("Ustonovit`: ");
val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
lcd.print(val);
int(sensor);
// if(val = sensors){  <----- ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА
//digitalWrite(Rele, LOW);
// }
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print("Fakt: ");
lcd.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // Почему "byIndex"?
// У вас может быть несколько IC на одной шине.
// 0 относится к первой IC
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: `if(val = sensors)` - нужен двойной знак ==. И тут ещё, `int PotenciometrPin = A0` - а так разве можно? Не так ли надо - 0xA0

Comment: @DrMcSheen, `A0` - это идентификатор первого пина АЦП. Объявлен в `arduino_pins.h` как `static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;`

Comment: Что вы ожидаете получить, преобразуя переменную типа `DallasTemperature` к `int`? Какой смысл вы вкладываете в это выражение?